# Objective C, code with C struct property, exception on calling getter

Tags: objective-c

Hi my code generates the following exception :

```
[Dot position]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x58a8.
```

What I do is I add instance of class Dot, to an NSArray (which is a property called dots) and then I try to get it back with;

```
Dot *last = [self.dots lastObject];
```

and print values inside C struct called position of type "CGPoint", `last.position.x` and `last.position.y`.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint position;
```

is witten inside Dot class .h file, which I also import to where I make a call to `CGPoint` getter.

Casting value returned from the array with `(Dot*)` does not help as well. Explicit addition of -(CGPoint) position to Dot .h file has no effect either.

Line generating the exception is:

```
NSLog(@"Dot added at: X : %f Y: %f", last.position.x, last.position.y);
```

Comment: Have you @synthesize'd the property?

Comment: Did you synthesize the properties?

Comment: I synthesize in my Dot.m file, do I have to do that in other files If I mention getters/setters for properties of Dot? 

@synthesize position = _position;

Comment: Also I noticed +[Dot position]:unrecognized selector sent to class 0x58a8. Seems like it tries to message the class itself not an instance of it?

Answer (score 1):

Error found, I had a Class method where I was returning, what I was thinking instance of Dot, I was doing it using [Dot alloc] init] where this returns Class object, I should have used [self alloc] init], to return instance of a Dot instead.